# componentWillMount executing twice

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I am calling an API before mounting a component but my code calling an API twice. My requirement is to display year data after getting Successful API call(it will return year data). If I use setState function inside componentWillMount then it should not call render method, but in my case render function is also called several times.

```
  componentWillMount(){
        // Year api call
          var oauth=GetAuthToken()
        if(this.props.options.apiName === 'year__c' ){
          var access_token=oauth.then((data) => {
            var temp
            temp=GetYear(data.access_token)
            temp.then((obj) => {
              this.setState({
                year:obj
              })
            })
          })       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as a side comment, I tend to avoid setting the state in the `componentWillMount` function since it will NOT trigger a re-render. Instead I use the `componentDidMount` function for this.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you are running into is that your setting state based off a promise being resolved. In a normal `componentWillMount` you setState, it updates the state, and then render() is called for the first time. When you introduce asynchronous api calls into the picture, then what happens is:

`componentWillMount` is executed, an API call is made and a Promise is created, while the Promise waits to be resolved code continues executing, React executes the Render() method on the component. At some point after rendering the Promise is resolved, setState is then called and since the Component has already been rendered then it will have to rerender due to a change in state.

The primary difference between the two being: If you just `setState` in the `componentWillMount` then it will happen before render occurs. If you have `setState` as part of a Promise being resolved, it will happen after the component has rendered thus causing multiple renders.